# Is it possible to have two controllers with the same route?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing, webapi

Is it possible to have two controllers in two assemblies with the same Route prefix attribute, but different Route attributes on the actions?

```
    [RoutePrefix("api/route")]
    public class Controller1 : ApiController
    {
        [Route("action1")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] string body)
        { }      

        [Route("{id}")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Delete(string id)
        { }    
    }

    [RoutePrefix("api/route")]
    public class Controller2 : ApiController
    {
        [Route("action2")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] string body)
        { }          
    }
```

Comment: i think if the methid route is different not a problem but if same route cant find it

Comment: In this case I thought it would be different route since Controller1.Action1 and Controller2.Action2 would be different route, but it seems when they share route prefix (api/route in this case) it does not work

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. What was my problem was that the first controller had defined a DELETE action with route "{id}". Since id was an unconstrained parameter Web Api could not see the difference between "api/route/action2" and "api/route/idtodelete".

I ended up creating a regex constraint on the delete which excludes "action2" and allows all alpanumeric characters. Now it works.

```
[HttpDelete]
[Route("{id:regex(^(?!action2)[a-zA-Z0-9]*$)}")]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are use the different Route for all action method than it will be working. But if you are using the same Route prefix with same Route action than it will give an error.